# Problema con if() con variables que incrementan y cambian segun la base de datos

Tags: javascript, html, firebase

Estoy haciendo una web para mi app móvil, la verdad es que no se mucho de Javascript (nada en realidad) y ya tengo casi todo lo que necesito, lo único que me está dando problemas es este código if(), el cual al parecer no reconoce las variables porque no me ejecuta el código que tengo dentro del mismo if(), siendo que si uso ese mismo código fuera del if() funciona perfectamente, por eso creo que debe ser problema de las variables dentro del if().

Este es el famoso if()

```
function btnmasAClick() {
    var numero = parseInt(document.getElementById('number').value, 10);
    numero = isNaN(numero) ? 0 : numero;
    numero++;
    document.getElementById('number').value = numero;
    var postElement4 = document.getElementById("postElement4");
    if (numero == postElement4) {  
    //hago algo
    }
    var updateStarCount4 = function(element4, value) {
    element4.textContent = value;
    };
    var starCountRef4 = firebase.database().ref().child("user").child("lista-user").child(numero+'').child("Edad");
    starCountRef4.on('value', function(snapshot) {
    updateStarCount4(postElement4, snapshot.val());
    });
}
```

Así muestro el dato recibido de la Database de Firebase en el el código HTML

```
<td id="postElement4"></td>
```

Si pudieran ayudarme sería genial, porque de Javascript no se mucho realmente...
Desde ya, muchas gracias por su tiempo!

Comment: En postElement4 te falta recoger su valor, estás comparando un número con un elemento DOM

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Estas comparando un elemento con un número, ya que `postElement4` no esta obteniendo el valor de la etiqueta si no la etiqueta cómo tal, así te deberia de funcionar :

```
function btnmasAClick() {
    var numero = parseInt(document.getElementById('number').value, 10);
    numero = isNaN(numero) ? 0 : numero;
    numero++;
    document.getElementById('number').value = numero;
    var postElement4 = parseInt(document.getElementById("postElement4").innerHTML,10);
    if (numero == postElement4) {  
    //hago algo
    }
    var updateStarCount4 = function(element4, value) {
    element4.textContent = value;
    };
    var starCountRef4 = firebase.database().ref().child("user").child("lista-user").child(numero+'').child("Edad");
    starCountRef4.on('value', function(snapshot) {
    updateStarCount4(postElement4, snapshot.val());
    });
}
```

Con eso obtienes el valor dentro de el elemento para que lo puedas comparar.

#### ¿Te funciono?

#### ¿El problema sigue?

#### ¿Cambio algo después de hacer esto?

Fuente :
Mozilla Developers. (Octubre 23,2012). ***element.innerHTML***. Abril 3,2018, de MDN Sitio web: https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML

Comment: Sigue sin funcionar con el código que me sugeriste... Muchas gracias, aún no logro encontrar el problema :/

Comment: ¿Te dio algún error en la consola o sucedió algo distinto?

Comment: @Christopher_Villa amigo, ya lo solucione con tu ayuda... era cosa de ordenar algunos códigos. El problema que tengo ahora es que el if() hace que se salte el primer dato que quiero comparar... Cuál podría ser la solución o un posible error?

Comment: ¿Es adicional al código que proporcionaste?

Comment: @MatíasNicolásNúñezRivas deberias abrir una nueva pregunta si esta respuesta ya soluciono el problema original.

Comment: @Klaimmore sí amigo, gracias!